# Elements of infinite order in CAT(0) groups

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, open-problem

In

E. Swenson, A cut point theorem for CAT(0) groups, J. Differential Geom. 53 (1999), no. 2, 327–358.

the author shows (Theorem 11) that if a group $G$ acts geometrically (i.e. properly discontinuously) and cocompactly by isometries on a CAT(0) space, then $G$ has an element of infinite order. However, every finite group is a CAT(0) group.

So I'm confused. Could specialist comment on this?

Comment: They might be (implicitly) assuming the CAT(0) space is unbounded

Comment: "geometrically (i.e. properly)" is not really standard: "geometrically" means properly **and** cocompactly **and** isometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is implicitly assuming that the CAT(0) space is unbounded in the first sentence of the proof of theorem 11 when they say "choose a geodesic ray". In the first paragraph of the section they say that rays are parametrized on $[0,\infty)$. In particular $G$ can not act geometrically on the space if it is finite.

Of course, as you point out, finite groups are CAT(0) in a trivial way, in that they act on (bounded) compact CAT(0) spaces geometrically. Although, this is a completely trivial uninteresting case so from the geometric perspective, so people don't really think about it.

Comment: Anyway, it's indeed awkward to state a theorem when there are trivial exceptions, and indeed the conclusion and that the author forgot to explicitly state that the space should be unbounded. (Some people, fortunately not all, indeed don't really think about it.)

Comment: Indeed alternatively, as Steve suggested, one can assume instead that the group is infinite since for a geometric action it's equivalent to unboundedness of the space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the proof is already assuming the group is infinite. Certainly it is true for infinite groups (this is well-known). Maybe somewhere the author mentions he's only talking about infinite groups?